# Machine Learning Algo to sort images

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-vision, click-through

I have a horizontal view, which has a list of images as shown below. These when clicked on the images they open up different URL’s, internal and external.

[image]
**Problem**

The problem is that the 1st image has an advantage of getting more clicks then rest of the images and the last images gets the least amount of clicks

**Question**

I was looking into some machine-learning algorithm, which would randomize the order of cards and then the most engaging cards is placed first on the order. Any idea on what/how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I doubt this requires any machine learning. Basic randomization in the beginning and simple stats will do.

Comment: Instead of `randomizing` I wanted to use something like `Multi-armed bandit`, so that I could exploit more and explore less.